# How to add a event handler to a ToolStripButton in C# code?

Tags: c#, eventhandler, toolstripbutton

Me again, and it's another problem with my *plugin parser* for my *c# browser*, I'm trying to add a eventhandler to make it to where when you hit the plugin button it does something. The reason i am having to do this in code is because it is loading the plugins from files, and they are not hard-coded. 
Here's my code, It will look pretty familar to the last one if you saw it

```
toolStrip1.Items.Add( pluginButton );
pluginButton.Image = Simple_Browse.Properties.Resources.plugin;
pluginButton.Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right;
pluginButton.ToolTipText = TitlePlugin;
pluginButton.Click += StartPlugin();
private EventHandler StartPlugin()
{

    PluginPage plgp = new PluginPage();
    plgp.Show();
    plgp.Text = PlgTitle2;

}
```

So the code is pretty basic, but im getting an error at **private EventHandler StartPlugin()** The error is *not all code paths return a value* Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to do this instead:

```
pluginButton.Click += StartPlugin; // not StartPlugin()
private void StartPlugin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PluginPage plgp = new PluginPage();
    plgp.Show();
    plgp.Text = PlgTitle2;
}
```

It looks like you may need to read a bit more on how delegates and event handlers work.

Comment: Very useful, You could also wire it up like pluginButton.Click += new EventHandler(StartPlugin);

Comment: @Joshua708: I can't help but feel like you were trolling :)  All of a sudden you are making valid suggestions on people's answers?

Comment: lol i studied more and found out

Answer (score 1):

You're requesting an `EventHandler` which means you have to return an `EventHandler`. In your handler there is no `return`, so this error is thrown.

You could use `private void StartPlugin()`. `void` doesn't request anything to return.

So your code will look like this:

```
pluginButton.Click += StartPlugin;

private void StartPlugin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PluginPage plgp = new PluginPage();
    plgp.Show();
    plgp.Text = PlgTitle2;
}
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type void to System.EventHandler, please help!

Comment: Please change `pluginButton.Click += StartPlugin();` to `pluginButton.Click += StartPlugin;` (remove the brackets). Have a look at my edit.

Comment: you also need to change it to StartPlugin(object sender, EventArgs e) at line 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
private EventHandler StartPlugin()
```

This line, specifically "EventHandler", means you're returning an EventHandler. Your code does not do this. To link the EventHandler with the button click, you dont just use a line, you also need a return, (e.x return button1.Click;) because if i used return null; it would just do the action once you binded it.

Comment: I figured it out, To make it less vague for people who need help, i edited it to explain more